# Where to find data about as many stars as possible?

Tags: star, galaxy, distances, galaxy-center, star-cluster

I need computer-readable data about as many stars as possible, with their:

- distance to the Earth (or Sun),
- their masses,

and if possible:

- coordinates,
- age,
- brightness
- distance to the center (Sagittarius-A) of the galaxy.

What is available? Which source of such data would be most recommended?

Comment: The GAIA catalog has most of those (or data they can be computed from), probably not mass or age though. http://cdn.gea.esac.esa.int/Gaia/gdr3/gaia_source/

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/8291/16685 It's difficult to estimate the mass of solitary stars, see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/51407/16685

Comment: Thank you, @GregMiller. I just installed the Gaia Sky app and it is amazing!